# What are some ways to generate a person's face using web technologies?

Tags: html, graphics, drawing, visualization

I'm in the process of creating a web application: a game. I have many randomly-generated non-player characters in a database. I can pull a lot of information about them - their height, weight, down to eye color, hair color, and hair style.

For this, I am solely interested in generating a graphical representation of the face. Currently the information is displayed with text in the nicest way possible, but I believe it's worth generating these faces for a more... human experience.

Problem is, I'm not artist. I wouldn't mind commissioning an artist for this system, but I wouldn't know where to start. Were it 2007, I'd naturally think to myself that using Flash would be the best choice. I'd love to see "breathing" simulated. However, since Flash is on its way out, I'm not sure of a solid solution.

With a previous game, I simply used layered .pngs to represent various aspects of the player's body: their armor, the face, the skin color. However, these solutions weren't very dynamic and felt very amateur. I can't go deep into this project feeling like that's an inferior way to present these faces, and I'm certain there's a better way.

Can anyone give some suggestion on how to pull this off well?

Comment: you should ask this in gamedev.stackexchange

Comment: Already did. I'm certain if I were to say "I need to put shapes on top of each other", it would "belong" here. Anyway, they weren't much help, but it seems canvas may be what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personnaly I would do some basic face/hair shapes using canvas api.
Then I would use your data like the color or of hair to fill this shapes.

You could also add parameters to the shape drawing functions which could represent height and weight of people.

For canvas api informations the mozilla tutorial is great :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial

You also have a nice cheat sheet
http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas_sheet/HTML5_Canvas_Cheat_Sheet.png

Comment: Thanks so much. Now to find an artist!

Answer (score 1):

Look into 'eigenfaces' - [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenface). The idea is that images of faces can be decomposed into linear combinations of a set of eigenfaces. So you can create a random face by randomly assigning a set of weights to the set of eigenfaces you have (there are sets on the web) and adding them together.

Might be overkill :) Not sure about the breathing.

Comment: That's really neat! I'm going for a more animated/drawn look, but this is really interesting. :}

Answer (score 0):

Canvas is nice but not so widely implemented, try generating them as requested by overlapping colored assets, it will look generic, but it is, you might want to have a wide variety of each hair or mustache, etc to make it look less repetitive, but if it works for zynga...